# URL redirection using powerdns and lua scripting

Tags: powerdns

I am building an internal whitelist browsing filter server for a business.
It is 95% operational.
PowerDNS intercepts the DNS request and the LUA script correctly determines if the URL is whitelisted.
The problem lies in the blacklist block page ... all I get is PAGE CANNOT BE DISPLAYED.
The LUA script is getting to this line but the actual redirect never occurs:
return 0, {{qtype=pdns.A, content="1.2.3.4"}}
The 1.2.3.4 is where I put the actual IP of the PowerDNS server itself.
Apache is not detecting that anything is getting to the server over port 80.
If I navigate to 1.2.3.4 I do get the block page so I know apache is configured correctly and I have ServerAlias set to * to accept all domains.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, you should be sure that domain resolved correctly using something like:

> nslookup example.com

2. Secondary, DNS-cache on the client computer may prevent correct resolving;
3. You should use 443 port additionaly to 80 for https browser connections;

I have the simular schema with powerdns+lua+nginx and everything work fine.
If you have no connection to the apache, that's mean your browser does not resolve domain correctly.

Comment: wow, it should be too late for you, but may be helpfull for someone.